# Apache2 server mime types

Tags: apache, apache2, download, mime-types, file-extension

I am trying to get my Apache2 web application to push an arbitrary file extension as an octet-stream when pointed to by a browser.

i.e. Someone goes to blahblah/examples/example1.xyz I want the browser to download the .xyz file rather than just display it.

I have tried adding .htaccess in the root of the web app including

```
AddType application/octet-stream xyz
```

And I have also tried to add the mime type to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf` and `/etc/mime.types` which is referenced as the types library from `mime.conf`.

I have read a good deal about this on the internet and still haven't gotten this working. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you have to add a `.` before the extension:

`AddType application/octet-stream .xyz`

Comment: According the document, it can be specified with or without a leading dot.

Comment: No dice. :( Just tried in the .htaccess and it didn't change anything. Also, in the mime.types file it seems that all of those don't have the .'s, although the format of that file is a bit different.

Comment: It renders the .xyz as text in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I wont recommend to use .htaccess with Rails apps. You have to configure
certain things for apache and passenger. Better use the config file in 
/etc/httpd/conf.d (or wherever you have configured your app on your server).
If you put the AddType line as follows (in my case, I had the problem with
downloadable Python Scripts):

```
AddType application/x-python-script .py
```

in the VirtualHosts section of your webapp config file, then you'll should 
be fine. If you really want to use .htaccess, do a

```
chmod 600 .htaccess
```

in your public folder, which causes apache not to ignore the file for savety
reasons (but again, you'll need to configure lots of other stuff then).