# Change font-family for Dyslexic in every website (bookmark)

Tags: javascript, css, font-face

My goal is simple (I think):
As the title suggest, I want a bookmark to change the font in every website in the Open-dyslexic web-font.

Because the font is on my server, I need to add a new font-face definition in the CSS of the page.

After that, the most simple thing I can think of is set the new font-family for the  tag.

But here I have the first problem. Nothing happens.

```
!function ()
{
    var newStyle = document.createElement( 'style' );
    newStyle.appendChild( document.createTextNode( "@font-face { font-family: 'OpenDyslexicRegular'; src: url('http://www.andrearastelli.net/font/OpenDyslexic-Regular.otf') format('opentype'); }" ) );
    document.head.appendChild( newStyle );
    console.debug( document.body.style.fontFamily );
    document.body.style.fontFamily = 'OpenDyslexicRegular, tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif';
    console.debug( document.body.style.fontFamily );
}();
```

This is my code, and if I remove the "OpenDyslexicRegular" part, the font actually change (for example if try to set a font-family: serif, everything works fine).

I guess the problem is the new font-face stuff that I add to the page.. looks like the new font isn't really loaded.

Or maybe is the extension? (but [CANIUSE/ttf](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf) shows that otf is a pretty valid font format)

---

Ok, this is a first change in the script (just to set every DOM element with the font-family I want)

```
!function ()
{
    var newStyle = document.createElement( 'style' );
    newStyle.appendChild( document.createTextNode( "" +
        "@font-face { " +
        "font-family: 'OpenDyslexicRegular'; " +
        "src: url('http://www.andrearastelli.net/font/OpenDyslexic-Regular.otf') format('opentype'); " +
        "}" ) );
    document.head.appendChild( newStyle );
    var allDomElement = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i=0; i<allDomElement.length; i++){
        allDomElement[i].style.fontFamily = 'OpenDyslexicRegular';
    }
    // document.body.style.fontFamily = 'OpenDyslexicRegular, tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif';
}();
```

The previous problem I described only occurs on Firefox (I haven't tested IE or Safari, for now).

---

This is an even more advanced version, with different font format in the CSS.

```
!function ()
{
    var newStyle = document.createElement( 'style' );
    newStyle.appendChild( document.createTextNode( "" +
        "@font-face { " +
        "font-family: 'OpenDyslexicRegular'; " +
        "src: url('http://www.andrearastelli.net/font/OpenDyslexic-Regular.otf') format('opentype'); " +
        "src:   url('http://www.andrearastelli.net/font/opendyslexic-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff')," +
        "       url('http://www.andrearastelli.net/font/opendyslexic-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype')," +
        "       url('http://www.andrearastelli.net/font/opendyslexic-regular-webfont.svg#opendyslexicregular') format('svg');"+
        "}" ) );
    document.head.appendChild( newStyle );
    var allDomElement = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i=0; i<allDomElement.length; i++){
        allDomElement[i].style.fontFamily = 'OpenDyslexicRegular';
    }
    // document.body.style.fontFamily = 'OpenDyslexicRegular, tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif';
}();
```

Because with firefox this is not working either.. I am thinking to drop FF support.

Comment: I'm using chrome and that works just fine, how are you triggering this on the page you are wishing to have this font?

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem on FireFox, but it's working on Chrome.

Comment: Just a side note here is that OpenType is not part of the WOFF spec and is considered 'experimental' by Mozilla, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Comment: @ars265 Thanks, I haven't searched (nor even thinked) about the Mozilla spec for the OTF.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand In Chrome works well.. so I need to think something to make all works in Firefox (just to let everyone use it.. )

Comment: May I suggest reading this and changing the font file if you are going to release it? http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

Comment: @ars265 I have read about it and I have implemented a more complete font-face in the JS.
But in Firefox I still have the same problems..

Answer (score 0):

As we've discussed in the comments, I would suggest using [Paul Irish's post](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) if you are going to release it to others so you get correct functionality across the board. Also using Chrome, I noticed that your font file is being returned as a `application/x-font-otf` but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871655/proper-mime-type-for-fonts) suggests that you should be using `font/opentype` or `application/x-font-opentype`. I wouldn't be surprised if Firefox has an issue with this.

Comment: How can I change the x-font-otf MIME to the correct one?
I can do this in the font-face rule.. or I need to build "something" to return the file with the correct MIME type?

Comment: It's going to be a server-side configuration and it will depend on with type of server you are running. I'm guessing since you're site is WordPress, you're running debian/Apache 2?

Comment: Well.. yes. I think I need some kind of .htaccess in the "font/" folder that let the browser decode the font-format the right way.
Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Depending on how much you want to read here is the long version: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html , or here is the shortened version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847234/apache2-server-mime-types

Comment: Maybe there is some mistake of mine.. but this should work, right?

`AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf`
`AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf`
`AddType application/font-woff .woff`

In a .htaccess placed in the same folder where the fonts are.

Comment: Yes, I believe that should work but only if .htaccess files are enabled. You would have to check with your provider.

Comment: Maybe.. but the first line in the .htaccess works well.. I have made a simple PHP script to show you the MIME type and the .htaccess content [link](http://andrearastelli.net/font/show_mime_type.php).
Because the first line works correctly, why the other just don't?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35848/discussion-between-ars265-and-andrea-rastelli)

Comment: I was wondering.. "what if I make some kind of 'caller' for the fonts?". I mean, instead of using this kind-of ugly .htaccess stuff, what if I build a PHP page that accept a GET parameter such as the name of the font I need, and through that I set the correct Content-Type based on the extensions of the file (or some kind of rule of mine).
This should let me get the same result as the .htaccess, am I wrong?

Comment: In theory yes, and you could set the type yourself that way as well.