# MP4 has no mime-type

Tags: video, mime-types, mp4

I've been having some issues embedding an MP4 file (particularly, Firefox Mac throws a "no video for mime-type can be found" error.)

I've SSH'd onto my host and checked the mime-type of the MP4 file, and it doesn't have one, where I would expect "video/mp4".

Is this an issue at the time the video is exported, or is this server configuration causing this?
I've added mp4 to my .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

> I've SSH'd onto my host and checked the mime-type of the MP4 file, and
>   it doesn't have one, where I would expect "video/mp4".

... and you will never find it. The mime type is not "attached" to a file. The mime-type is used for the HTTP request/response to identify the type of the content.

So the way you must setup your mime-type is always **on the webserver you are using**... If you said you are using SSH (and .htaccess), so probably you are in a Linux/UNIX-like system. Therefore probably you are using Apache. So take a look at this: [Apache2 server mime types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847234/apache2-server-mime-types) or just Google for something like "setting up mime type apache" and so on...

More: Oh yes, you may setup it on your .htaccess as well... but check if your .htaccess is really enabled on your apache settings and/or virtual host.