# Php file downloading issues?

Tags: php

Currently I'm using following php code to download file.

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
timeout();
//require_once("config.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['front_username']) && isset($_SESSION['front_username']) == "" &&
    !isset($_SESSION['front_password']) && isset($_SESSION['front_password']) == "" &&
    !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_id']) == "") {
    header("Location:login.php");   
    exit();
}
$file_get = $_GET['filename'];  
$tmp = explode(".",$file_get);  
$file_name1 = substr($file_get, 33);    
switch ($tmp[count($tmp)-1]) {
    case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
    case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
    case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
    case "docx":
    case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
    case "csv":
    case "xls":
    case "xlsx": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
    case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    case "tif":
    case "tiff": $ctype="image/tiff"; break;
    case "psd": $ctype="image/psd"; break;
    case "bmp": $ctype="image/bmp"; break;
    case "ico": $ctype="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"; break;
    default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}   
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name1."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize("upload_doc/$file_get"));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("upload_doc/$file_get" );
?>
```

It's downloading correctly if the uploaded file name is **alphanumeric**. But If the uploaded file name has this text e.g `my doc #2.doc` or `dev & developer.doc`then it's downloading but not showing. In my downloaded folder I see `my doc`.

I don't understand what's the wrong in my code, Can someone tell me ?

Comment: The first problem I see is in this line  **$file_name1 = substr($file_get, 33);**   You are truncating the first 32 characters from the filename. Why is it so ?

Comment: @Diptendu for example : Original uploaded file name is rename to : `35dbde7e8eab023248adf616747caf6e-bind candidate #2.doc` and when I download it I want to show user's uploaded name only.

Comment: ok. so you want to remove the MD5 part. Got it. Thanks!!

Comment: @Diptendu Exactly :)

Comment: Can you try changing this line header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name1."\";" ); to header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\'".$file_name1."\';" ); and see if it works?

Comment: No it's not working. I see `-'bind candidate -';`

Comment: can you try header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".urlencode($file_name1)."\";" );

Comment: now I see `bind+candidate+ (1)`

Answer (score 0):

& and # are URL special characters.

When trying to access your files, you should encode any special characters the right way using urlencode PHP method :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Maybe you should manage you mime type at Apache level for security purposes :
[Apache2 server mime types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847234/apache2-server-mime-types)

Or if you can't, filter your get parameters to avoid users to request any path on your server :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php